# Temporarily stop a for control flow

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in liste:
    inp = input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og 3 ')
    if inp > (len(i)-1):
        print 'HOOOOORE'
    elif i[inp] == 'T':
        print 'Du er videre til neste rom'
        print 'Du er naa i rom ' + str(j)
        j = j + 1
    elif i[inp] == 'B':
        print 'Du falt i et bunnlost hull og er na do'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'F':
        print 'Du dode i en felle'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'M':
        print 'Du slapp unna'
        break
```

If the user enters a number that is greater than the length of the `array i`, I want to make  the for structure stop if that is possible. That way the araay wont run away from my counter `j`

I solved my problem by using a while statement. But i am still interested in how I can solve this by using a for statement. If i[inp] is not == T I want to operate on the same i again.

```
def spill(liste):
i = 0
j = 2
while j < len(liste):
    inp = input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og ' + str(len(liste[i])-1) + ': ')
    if inp > (len(liste[i])-1):
        print 'HOOOOORE'
        inp = input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og 3 denne gangen: ')
    elif liste[i][inp] == 'T':
        print 'Du er videre til neste rom fordi denne doren var trygg'
        print 'Du er naa i rom ' + str(j)
        j = j + 1
    elif liste[i][inp] == 'B':
        print 'Her er det et hull. Ikke ga her'
    elif liste[i][inp] == 'F':
        print 'Her er det en felle'
    elif liste[i][inp] == 'M':
        print 'Du slapp unna'
        break
```

This code does just that as you can see.

Comment: The `break` will stop the `for` loop. You are already using that in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by stop? Do you mean to go to the next iteration and get the next element `i` of `liste`? And we can't know how your counter `j` behaves. Did you miss to paste some code?

Comment: see my answer - just use a `while` inside a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

What really solves you problem is to put that `input()` into a `while`, and use `raw_input()` instead:

```
for i in liste:
    inp = raw_input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og 3 ')
    while inp > (len(i)-1):
        inp = raw_input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og 3 ') # you may want to change the text here
    if i[inp] == 'T':
        print 'Du er videre til neste rom'
        print 'Du er naa i rom ' + str(j)
        j = j + 1
    elif i[inp] == 'B':
        print 'Du falt i et bunnlost hull og er na do'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'F':
        print 'Du dode i en felle'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'M':
        print 'Du slapp unna'
        break
```

Comment: And while you're at it, change it to `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

You use break. you already did in your code:

```
for i in liste:
    inp = input('Skriv et tall mellom 0 og 3 ')
    if inp > (len(i)-1):
        print 'HOOOOORE'
        continue
    elif i[inp] == 'T':
        print 'Du er videre til neste rom'
        print 'Du er naa i rom ' + str(j)
        j = j + 1
    elif i[inp] == 'B':
        print 'Du falt i et bunnlost hull og er na do'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'F':
        print 'Du dode i en felle'
        break
    elif i[inp] == 'M':
        print 'Du slapp unna'
        break
```

Comment: I'm unsure whether he wants to `break` out of the loop...his question is very unclear imho.

Comment: I do now want to break out. I just want to run the same code again on the same object, but now with different input. Like you do with a while statement.

Comment: replace break with continue then. That should re-execute at the start of the loop and take new input.

Comment: but it would also take the next element of `liste`, which is afaik not what he wants